# Allow spectators to see vote tallies in primaries

Tags: feature-request, election

Currently, it appears that you can't see the vote totals on nominees during the primaries if you don't have enough reputation to vote: presumably, that's because the voting widget is disabled.

It would be great to be able to see how the election is doing as a spectator. In case it isn't clear, as it stands now, voters while voting get to see vote tallies: I'm requesting people who aren't voting be given that same information. For transparency and/or idle curiosity.

> #### Edit:
>
> I'm interested in providing the same level of information for voters and non-voters alike, but if you're interested in getting rid of the tallies for voters entirely, you'll want to see the request: [Do not show the score for users during primaries.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76412/do-not-show-the-score-for-users-during-primaries)

[image: Primary ballot without tallies]

Comment: Funny, I was about to make the _opposite_ suggestion :)

Comment: Being able to see the partial results of an election can skew the final results of the election. You must not allow the results of an election to ruin the results of an election.

Comment: @badp blind voting? Or do you see vote tallies as a spectator now, and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: @ALLCAPS I'm not here to start a thing about whether voters are allowed to see running tallies; I'm just requesting spectators get the same information voters get *now*.

Comment: It's like an ice cream headache. Ice cream is fantastic. It's creamy and delicious and full of little bits of things you like to eat like Oreos. Oreos are the king of cookies with respect to ice cream (Oreo haters, you can just go die). But if you eat too much ice cream your head freezes solid and you can't talk let alone eat any more ice cream. Don't let ice cream ruin your ice cream. Don't let election results ruin your election. (Don't let Mark Trapp ruin the your election, either. I heard he hates Oreos.)

Comment: @ALLCAPS again, I'm not starting a thing about whether tallies should be shown in general. I know it's easy to get tripped up on a request when there are a whole 5 lines to read, but I'm asking for people *not voting* (and thus, *not being skewed by the tallies simpliciter*) to be able to observe.

Comment: @ALLCAPS How does your ice cream metaphor relate to the current practice of hiding votes to non-eligibles and *showing* them to those that can vote?

Comment: @ALLCAPS http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76412/do-not-show-the-score-for-users-during-primaries

Comment: +1.  I'm not sure if I think showing vote tallies during the primaries are a good idea, but they I do think showing spectators the same information as voters is a good idea.  That being said, the people who have less than 150 reputation are either in the penalty box or are not active enough on the site for this information to hold that much importance.