# Election page shows zero votes instead of negative until I view vote count

Tags: bug, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not show the score for users during primaries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76412/do-not-show-the-score-for-users-during-primaries)

On the elections page, candidates with a negative number of votes show zero votes until I specifically request the vote count, either by voting or by explicitly requesting it.

I'm using Safari 5 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2.

Comment: Note, it's not just negatives.  It's all votes.  It seems that the totals just aren't keeping up or being calculated correctly.  But the relative position is still seemingly correct (high totals have high votes, low totals are mostly downvotes, etc)...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76412/do-not-show-the-score-for-users-during-primaries

Comment: @random - So the solution is showing inaccurate votes? Really?

Comment: You don't think you'd be swayed at all by how others have voted?

Comment: @random That doesn't work in the positive direction?

Comment: @random: Not sure I see the logic there.  The relative voting is still there, so wouldn't that sway people as well?  Why not just hide it and let users click to see the votes if you're trying to prevent herd mentality?

Comment: @irc - Well said.

Comment: I still disagree with that feature request and @random I don't see how this makes it any better.