# No link to the origin post for old questions closed as duplicates

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

There is no link in special duplicate block to the origin question for old posts. Check out [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112127/339911):

> [image: no link]

The most [recent duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353637/339911) contain links in the block:

> [image: has link]

Comment: See also: [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339706/622284) to the post notice redesign announcement.