# Why can we see the votes in an ongoing election?

Tags: discussion, election, moderator-primaries

I find that my expectations of a nominated person and where my votes should go are affected by what number I see next to them, even if I don't want it to. I feel I gravitate towards nominees who already have a larger number of votes, and away from ones with smaller.

Is there a benefit to this that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not asking for personal advice. I'm asking what the reasons for making it visible are. I can't see it discussed anywhere else. As far as I'm aware, I'm noticing a problem that probably affects a lot of people who don't notice it.

Comment: Related: [Do not show the score for users during primaries](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76412/do-not-show-the-score-for-users-during-primaries)

Comment: Ah, that answers my question. Thanks @hichris123.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Helped him solve :)

Comment: In Canada it is [apparently forbidden](http://www.thestar.com/news/canada/2011/04/21/posting_election_results_to_twitter_facebook_may_be_illegal.html) to post election results from one part of the country before polls have closed all over in case it influences how people vote.

Answer (score 4):

The same reason you can see votes next to questions and answers.  People are just curious, it doesn't have to relate to influencing your decision (though some people *want* to be influenced).  I do agree, however, that it distracts from the users who have less votes (I am not just saying this because my nomination has the lowest amount of votes in the election, and I am *not* telling you to go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/election) link with >= 150 reputation and to vote for me).  If you completely cannot stand this, just have this jQuery userscript:

```
$('.vote-count-post').text('Do not ask of me a number.');
```