# Can't see vote scores in the primaries on Super User

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election

I only have 103 reputation points on [Super User](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Super_User). When I went to look at the results of the primaries, I noticed that I don't see vote scores. Are they meant to only be public to eligible voters or is this a bug?

Comment: Related stuff: I made [a related post on MSU](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1993/moderator-election-vote-counts-arent-showing-up-for-me), and was told that there's [also an MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/who-can-split-the-votes-in-the-primary-election) on the same topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug - it's currently designed that you'll need at least 150 reputation (the voting threshold) in order to see the vote score.

[There's an open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76410/allow-spectators-to-see-vote-tallies-in-primaries) to allow all users to see the vote scores. Though, at the same time, there's also an [opposing feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76412/do-not-show-the-score-for-users-during-primaries) to not show the vote scores to anyone.